# How to enter my text with emoticon on contenteditable div to display yet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I changed my `textarea` to `div contenteditable` for display emoticon yet just enter emoticon's value with text. So I used jQuery `.bind`.

Now I cannot enter any text on `contenteditable div`.

How to enter my text with emoticon on `contenteditable div` to display yet.

Here is my work: ( here 888 is all of my php `'.$id.'` )

```js
var smileys = {
    ':)': '<img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" border="0" alt="" />',
 ':-)': '<img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" border="0" alt="" />',
 ':D': '<img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" border="0" alt="" />',
};

function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
function smilyMe(msg) {
    msg = msg.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    for (var key in smileys) {
        msg = msg.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(key), "g"), smileys[key]);
    }
    return msg;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#comment").bind("keyup", function(e) {
   var EID = $(this).attr('class').replace('com','');
    $(".com"+EID).html(smilyMe($(".com"+EID).val()));
  });
  
  $('.showhide_emobox').click(function(event){
 var EID = $(this).attr("id");
 $("#emobox"+EID).slideToggle();
  });

  $(".embtn").click(function(event){
    var emotiText = $(event.target).attr("alt");
    var EID = $(this).attr('id').replace('','');
    var prevMsg = $(".com"+EID).val();
    $(".com"+EID).val(prevMsg + emotiText);
    $(".com"+EID).html(smilyMe($(".com"+EID).val()));
    $('#emobox'+EID).fadeToggle();
  });

});
```

```css
#maintbox {
    top:50px;
 position:relative;
 min-height: 38px;
 width: 100%;
}
div.chat {
    width: 100%;
}

#comment {
    font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;
 font-size:12px;
   min-height: 25px;
   color:#000;
   top:0; left:0; z-index:998; background: transparent;
 border: 2px solid #ccc;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    resize: none;
    padding-right:50px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#right {
    position:absolute;
    top: -8px;
    right:0px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    width: 50px;
    z-index:999;
}
#right img {
    cursor:pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:20px;
}
.emobox {
    background:#fff;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:visible;
    width:200px;
    bottom:25px;
    left:-176px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    z-index:9999;
}
.emobox img {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="maintbox">
  <div class="chat">
   <div contenteditable name="comment" tabindex="4" id="comment" class="com888" placeholder="Type here..."></div>
  </div>
      
     <div id="right">
     <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fez/512/FEZ-05-128.png" id="uploadMedia" />
     <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/big-smile-256x256.png"  id="888" class="showhide_emobox" />
        <div id="emobox888" class="emobox">
  <img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" alt=":)" class="embtn" id="888" />
  <img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" alt=":-)" class="embtn" id="888" />
  <img src="http://www.html5gamedevs.com/public/style_emoticons/default/wacko.png" alt=":D" class="embtn" id="888" />
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
  
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c0d3.googlecode.com/files/jquery-latest.pack.js'></script>
```

Comment: Why all three images inside `<div id="emobox888">` have the same `id` and `href` when they have a different `alt`? And why I cannot see them? I see textarea and two icons inside (one smiley and camera).

Comment: If you try to write anything or write :) on textarea, textarea display none. Here is my problem.  emobox working well.

Comment: Where should it appear? At least, I don't see any trace of textarea in CSS, JavaScript - and also in HTML.